# Can't scroll down after using Locomotive Scroll

Tags: php, locomotive-scroll

I'm making a home page and when I implement Locomotive Scroll it is stuck on my slider and I can't scroll down. I tried to hide my slider and it worked. Any idea why it's not working with my slider?
[image]

```
const scroller = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
  smooth: true
});
```